# Não consigo rodar o servidor mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Sou novo em relação ao mongoDB, então não sei como resolver isso.

SO: Windows 7

segue o comando:

```
C:\Users\Rodrigo>mongod
```

e o erro obtido:

> 2018-03-21T16:09:27.837-0300 I CONTROL  [main]
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.841-0300 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't
>   have journal ing enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want
>   durability. 2018-03-21T16:09:27.844-0300 I CONTROL  [main]
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.861-0300 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or
>   later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.874-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
>   starting : pid=2 232 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 32-bit
>   host=Rodrigo-PC 2018-03-21T16:09:27.876-0300 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vis ta/Windows Server 2008
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.880-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v3.2.19-22-ge 7960bb2b6 2018-03-21T16:09:27.884-0300 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] git version: e7960bb2b64 f154cbe5d0de04e2f0ed373fc92d0
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.886-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
>   tcmalloc 2018-03-21T16:09:27.888-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   modules: none 2018-03-21T16:09:27.890-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   build environment: 2018-03-21T16:09:27.891-0300 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]     distarch: i386 2018-03-21T16:09:27.894-0300 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: i386
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.897-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>   2018-03-21T16:09:27.902-0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndList en: 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine
>   'wiredTiger' is not av ailable with this build of mongod. Please
>   specify a different storage engine exp licitly, e.g.
>   --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating 2018-03-21T16:09:27.906-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Comment: Você tem a pasta C:\data\db\ ? está executando como administrador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você ja tem tudo o que precisa (incluindo a pasta C:\data\db) então o problema provavelmente é um conflito de versões do seu sistema com o mongodb. Acredito que o seu SO é de 32 bits, então é necessário mudar o seu mecanismo de armazenamento para os mecanismos que são adequados para o sistema de 32 bits, como o mmapv1.

Execute o comando abaixo dentro da pasta onde o seu mondodb esta instalado:

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [caminho_da_pasta_db]  //<-- geralmente o caminho padrão é c:\data\db
```

> Pergunta semelhante no stackoverflow :
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai